# Linux Apache hybrid basic auth - ldap and .htpasswd file credentials at the same time

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, authentication, ldap

I have some api covered by reverse proxy. I have configured basic auth with ldap AD credentials and it works like a charm. But there are some users from external organization that don't have AD account.

Is it possible to configure ldap and .htpasswd authentication at the same time? That's why I call it hybrid basic auth.

I have only tried this in nginx with satisfy operator but in nginx for ldap auth I have to compile it from sources. This is not acceptable for my client.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I know it is possible :)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 <Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  ProxyPass  http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/

  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Please enter Your credentials"

  AuthBasicProvider ldap file
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://10.10.10.1:389/OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=int,DC=company,DC=pl?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
  AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=tech_user,OU=Special_Users,OU=Users,OU=Company,DC=int,DC=company,DC=pl"
  AuthLDAPBindPassword "some_password"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd

  Require valid-user
  Satisfy All
 </Location>

 ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Excellent :-) What would make a good answer a great one is [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/737004/edit) it to add context. For example adding the file name, and a bit of description of what exactly is happening there.